# Drupal 7.2, Views: Adding Author's Name of a node

Tags: views, entities

I'm sure this is VERY basic, but after 1/2 day or searching, I am finally posting for help.

I have a simple view that is displaying a list of node titles & other fields (view count, comment count, etc). I can't find how to add the name of the author who wrote the corresponding node to a field.

For example- the final result SHOULD look like this-

Title
by: Author Name
Views: #  Comments: #

I have everything else working- just can't figure out how to add the author name field. What's the secret?
Thanks guys!

Comment: Trying to do something similar, but in creating a dynamic view.  I want user tweets block (using Twitter module) to automatically show on the nodes authored by them. Since I don't know this value, cannot use a filter. ...I am using relationship "Content:Author" and have tried using contextual filter "User:Name" with "provide default" of "Content ID from URL".  It is still displaying tweets from all users.

Comment: @Greta I think this will solve your problem :- [My solution on Calling block on specific user login][1]


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71684/can-we-call-a-custom-block-inside-our-hook-block-view/71827#71827

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a connection between users and content. This is done through relationships. Go to relationships and select Content: Author. Then if you add fields you will see several new fields to choose from including User: Name. When configuring User: Name there will be a drop down that lets you choose which relationship since there is only one choose that one.

Comment: Awesome. This worked. FYI- in case anyone else needs this, that syntax is actually Content: Author in the relationships portion, and User: Name in the field list in D7.2  Thanks for the help!

Comment: ADAM S - U R A GOD!!!!!!!!!!!! I spent ages trying to do this, I had no idea about having to use "relationships" you have made my day! THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: Trying to do something similar, but in creating a dynamic view.  I want user tweets block (using Twitter module) to automatically show on the nodes authored by them. (Similar to what Author Pane module does.) Since I don't know this value, cannot use a filter. ...I am using relationship "Content:Author" and have tried using contextual filter "User:Name" with "provide default" of "Content ID from URL", among other options.  It is still displaying tweets from all users. ...Is this posts solution applicable, but I am missing something?