# How do I create a user relationship to show author name in Views?

Tags: views, 6

I want to show node title and it's author but I'm not able to find how to show the author name. I don't see Content:Author in Relationship.

How do I configure Views to show it?

Comment: I believe this has been answered before:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5868/drupal-7-2-views-adding-authors-name-of-a-node

Comment: No it does not seem to apply for D6 as I've mentioned(Content:Author)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 6 you don't need a relationship for the author name of a node, it is directly available in the fields' list.

[image: Views Drupal 6 Author name]