# Can we call a custom block inside our hook_block_view()?

Tags: hooks, blocks, commerce

I have a module of type block.Now based on the user i want to display different blocks .
So i have a written the module but my dilemma is if its possible to call a block(default) inside our custom block? Here's my code m trying !

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function sample_module_block_info() {
  $blocks['current_posts'] = array(
    'info' => t('Current Users Of the Drupal Website'), //The name that will appear in the block list.
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE, //Default
  );
  return $blocks;
}
function sample_module_block_view($delta = '')
 { 

 $block = array();
global $user;
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'current_posts':
      $block['subject'] = t('Logged in User Currently');
$block['content']=$user->name;
      break;
/**
 switch ($delta) {
 case 'current_posts': 
global $user;
print "The current user is: ";
print $user->name;
if($user->name == "admin")
print " This Shit Works ";
*/
    }
  return $block;
}
   ?>
```

Now in block['content'] i want to display another block!
Can somebody lead me to how to do this ? If possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can load any block

```
....
$block['content']= sample_module_block_content();
....
function sample_module_block_content(){
  $block = block_load('module_name', 'block_name');      
  return _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));        
}
```

Comment: Ya your code is awesome if we have a module of our own but I want to call a default block which doesn't come in module.Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: if you want call standard block : module_name can be block or system, user, node, search. Block_name - find on blocks page. You can check all blocks names and it's modules in database in table 'block', check two columns 'module' and 'delta'

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code and works perfectly :-(Code to call a default block inside a custom module )

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function sample_module_block_info() {
  $blocks['current_posts'] = array(
    'info' => t('Current Users Of the Drupal Website'), //The name that will appear in the block list.
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE, //Default
  );
  return $blocks;
}
function sample_module_block_view($delta = '')
 { 

 $block = array();
global $user;
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'current_posts':
      $block['subject'] = t('Logged in User Currently');
$block['content']=call_block();
      break;
/**
 switch ($delta) {
 case 'current_posts': 
global $user;
print "The current user is: ";
print $user->name;
if($user->name == "admin")
print " This Shit Works ";
*/
    }
  return $block;
}
function call_block(){
  $block = block_load('system', 'powered-by');      
  return _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));        
}
```

This is the module file and after that u need an info file of the module .